# Converted Audio File has noise while Converting form mp3 to wave

Tags: java, audio

Following is my Code For Converting mp3 file to wave using jave 1.0.2 jar

```
 File source = new File("D://Test1.mp3");
                                    File target = new File("F://Test.wav");
                                    AudioAttributes audio = new AudioAttributes();
                                    audio.setCodec("pcm_s32be");
                                    audio.setChannels(1);
                                    audio.setSamplingRate(8000);
                                    EncodingAttributes attrs = new EncodingAttributes();
                                    attrs.setFormat("wav"); 

                                    attrs.setAudioAttributes(audio);
                                    Encoder encoder = new Encoder();
                                    encoder.encode(source, target, attrs);
```

Comment: is there still noise if you change sampling rate to 44000?

Comment: yes still noise is there.